# nginx container networking DNS resolves to incorrect IP address

Tags: docker, container, podman

The patches-nginx container is incorrectly resolving the IP address of patches-backend within the nginx process but not when I check it manually from the nginx command line.

I have nginx running as a proxy inside a podman container though Googling seems to show this problem exists on Docker as well and is without resolution.

In the nginx logs I see:

```
2023/07/12 19:33:52 [error] 24#24: *52 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.89.0.119, server: patches.lan, request: "GET /api/auth HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.89.0.117:9000/api/auth", host: "10.10.25.131", referrer: "https://10.10.25.131/"

        10.89.0.119 - - [12/Jul/2023:19:33:52 +0000]
        "GET /api/auth HTTP/1.1" 502 559
        "https://10.10.25.131/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        Certificate: "-"
        Client Key: "-"
```

We see that the upstream host is 10.89.0.117. I go to check the nginx config - proxy_pass points to `patches-backend`:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include    /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    log_format custom '
        $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]
        "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent
        "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"
        Certificate: "$ssl_client_cert"
        Client Key: "$ssl_client_raw_cert"
        ';

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name patches.lan 10.10.25.131 ;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name patches.lan 10.10.25.131 ;


        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log custom;

        # Client-facing certificate and key
        ssl_certificate /patches/server_certs/patches.lan.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /patches/server_certs/patches.lan.key;


        # Disable client certificate request
        ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;




        location /api {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;



            # Set X-SSL-CERT header with client certificate
            proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;

            proxy_pass https://patches-backend:9000;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;



            # Set X-SSL-CERT header with client certificate
            proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;

            proxy_pass http://patches-frontend:3000;
        }
    }
```

Everything is as it should be. I check curl against the DNS name from the nginx container to the backend:

```
root@87c91993cab5:/# curl patches-backend:9000
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

This is also as it should be. However when I check `podman inspect patches-backend` I see:

```
...SNIP...
"Networks": {
                    "host-bridge-net": {
                         "EndpointID": "",
                         "Gateway": "10.89.0.1",
                         "IPAddress": "10.89.0.120",
                         "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                         "IPv6Gateway": "",
                         "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                         "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                         "MacAddress": "3e:c9:de:23:44:a6",
                         "NetworkID": "host-bridge-net",
                         "DriverOpts": null,
                         "IPAMConfig": null,
                         "Links": null,
                         "Aliases": [
                              "e9485d2c8cf7"
                         ]
                    }
               }
...SNIP...
```

patches-backend is clearly 10.89.0.120 but somehow, in the context of nginx, it is resolving that hostname to `10.89.0.117` (as we saw in the logs) which doesn't exist anywhere on the network.

I'm at a total loss as to how this could happen. The nginx config has the hostname not the IP so it isn't a hard-coded IP somewhere and as shown above the nginx container correctly resolves `patches-backend` when checked from the command line. However the nginx process somehow gets a non-existent IP address. None of my containers have the IP 117:

```
# Reverse search 10.89.0.117 (the wrong IP) across all containers
[grant@patches2 opt]$ podman inspect -f '{{.Name}}' $(podman ps -a -q --format='{{.ID}}') | xargs -I {} sh -c 'podman inspect -f "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" {} | grep -w 10.89.0.117 && echo Container: {}'
# Reverse search 10.89.0.120 (the correct IP) across all containers
[grant@patches2 opt]$ podman inspect -f '{{.Name}}' $(podman ps -a -q --format='{{.ID}}') | xargs -I {} sh -c 'podman inspect -f "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" {} | grep -w 10.89.0.120 && echo Container: {}'
10.89.0.120
Container: patches-backend
```

I can't imagine how this is happening and I'm not able to reproduce it in any simple example. Worth noting is that there are is no further configuration being applied to nginx. This is the only configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is that `nginx` caches the DNS resolution on config load in most cases, restarting `nginx` would refresh the DNS cache and pick up the new IP address or you could wait for the TTL to expire.

There is  a [great answer at https://serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/a/593003) with a better explanation and tricks you can do with a DNS resolver and `nginx` variables to have new lookups on each request.